# Run Pytorch stacked model on Colab TPU

Tags: pytorch, google-colaboratory, huggingface-transformers, tpu, google-cloud-tpu

I am trying to run this my model on Colab Multi core TPU but I really don't know how to do it. I tried [this tutorial notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/github/pytorch/xla/blob/master/contrib/colab/multi-core-alexnet-fashion-mnist.ipynb) but I got some error and I can't fix it but I think there is maybe simpler wait for to do it.

About my model:

```
class BERTModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,...):
        super().__init__()
        if ...:
            self.bert_model = XLMRobertaModel.from_pretrained(...)   # huggingface XLM-R
        elif ...:
            self.bert_model = others_model.from_pretrained(...)   # huggingface XLM-R
        
        ... # some other model's parameters
        
    def forward(self,...):
        bert_input = ...
        output = self.bert_model(bert_input)
        
        ... # some function that process on output
        
    def other_function(self,...):
        # just doing some process on output. like concat layers's embedding and return ...
        
class MAINModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,...):
        super().__init__()
        
        print('Using model 1')
        self.bert_model_1 = BERTModel(...)
        
        print('Using model 2')
        self.bert_model_2 = BERTModel(...)
        
        self.linear = nn.Linear(...)
        
    def forward(self,...):
        bert_input = ...
        bert_output = self.bert_model(bert_input)
        linear_output = self.linear(bert_output)
   
        return linear_output
```

Can you please tell me how to run a model like my model on Colab TPU? I used Colab PRO to make sure Ram memory is not a big problem. Thanks you so so much.

Comment: It is always helpful when you share the error message that you receive. Please add the complete stacktrace to your question.

Answer (score 1):

I would work off the examples here: https://github.com/pytorch/xla/tree/master/contrib/colab

Maybe start with a simpler model like this: https://github.com/pytorch/xla/blob/master/contrib/colab/mnist-training.ipynb

In the pseudocode you shared, there is no reference to the `torch_xla` library, which is required to use PyTorch on TPUs. I'd recommend starting with on of the working Colab notebooks in that directory I shared and then swapping out parts of the model with your own model. There are a few (usually like 3-4) places in the overall training code you need to modify for a model that runs on GPUs using native PyTorch if you want to run that model on TPUs. See [here](https://github.com/pytorch/xla/blob/master/API_GUIDE.md#running-on-multiple-xla-devices-with-multiprocessing) for a description of some of the changes. The other big change is to wrap the default dataloader with a ParallelLoader as shown in the example MNIST colab I shared

If you have any specific error you see in one of the Colabs, feel free to open an issue : https://github.com/pytorch/xla/issues